# Data feed created in php doesn't validate

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have to following code to upload data to a third party. However when I test it in a validator I get the following error:

```
Undefined root elements:items and text/xml media type is not specific enough.
```

I have no clue has what I need to change.

Here is the code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>';
mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
$query_feed = "SELECT * FROM dat_table WHERE time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()";
$feed = mysql_query($query_feed, $dconn) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_feed = mysql_fetch_assoc($feed)){


    echo'<item>
            <name>'.$row_feed['Name'].'</name>
            <email>'.$row_feed['email'].'</email>
            <date>'.$row_feed['Date'].'</date>
            <description>'.$row_feed['Make'].' '.$row_feed['Model'].' '.$row_feed['Type'].'</description>
            <logon>'.$row_feed['Logon'].'</logon>
            <category>'.$row_feed['Type'].'/'.$row_feed['Make'].'</category>
            <product_search_code>'.$row_feed['Product_search_code'].'</product_search_code>
            <order_ref>'.$row_feed['Invoice'].'</order_ref>
            <product_link>'.$row_feed['Product_link'].'</product_link>
            <customer_ref>'.$row_feed['Invoice'].'</customer_ref>
            <amount>'.$row_feed['Price'].'</amount> 
            <currency>GBP</currency>
        </item>';
        }
echo '</items>
';
```

This is RSS out put in validator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items><item>
<name>Name of customer</name>
<email>customer@gmail.com</email>
<date>03/04/2014</date>
<description>Roland FP80BK Piano</description>
<logon>www.pianoandkeyboardshoponline.co.uk</logon>
<category>Piano/Roland</category>
<product_search_code>264</product_search_code>
<order_ref>8336</order_ref>
<product_link>http://www.pianoandkeyboardshop.co.uk/Roland-FP80-Digital-Piano-in-Satin-Black/264</product_link>
<customer_ref>8336</customer_ref>
<amount>1500.00</amount>
<currency>GBP</currency>
</item><item>
next item etc
---
--
</item><items>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create a generic XML document or a RSS feed?

Comment: I am trying to create a feed for feefo to read sales data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text/xml content type is for generic XML documents. For a feed, try using

```
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
```

But anyway, in order to create a valid RSS you have to use the correct RSS tags (Something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Example)). You seem to use a lot of custom tags instead, so I don't know what exactly you need to do. The easiest solution would be to use namespaces for your custom tags, so something like:

```
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:mytags="http://mytags.something.net">
    <channel>
    <title>My RSS Title</title>
    <description>This is the description for my RSS feed</description>
    <link>http://www.someexamplerssdomain.com/main.html</link>
    <mytags:items>';
mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
$query_feed = "SELECT * FROM dat_table WHERE time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()";
$feed = mysql_query($query_feed, $dconn) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_feed = mysql_fetch_assoc($feed)){
    echo '<mytags:item>
        <mytags:name>'.$row_feed['Name'].'</mytags:name>
        <mytags:email>'.$row_feed['email'].'</mytags:email>
        <mytags:date>'.$row_feed['Date'].'</mytags:date>
        <mytags:description>'.$row_feed['Make'].' '.$row_feed['Model'].' '.$row_feed['Type'].'</mytags:description>
        <mytags:logon>'.$row_feed['Logon'].'</mytags:logon>
        <mytags:category>'.$row_feed['Type'].'/'.$row_feed['Make'].'</mytags:category>
        <mytags:product_search_code>'.$row_feed['Product_search_code'].'</mytags:product_search_code>
        <mytags:order_ref>'.$row_feed['Invoice'].'</mytags:order_ref>
        <mytags:product_link>'.$row_feed['Product_link'].'</mytags:product_link>
        <mytags:customer_ref>'.$row_feed['Invoice'].'</mytags:customer_ref>
        <mytags:amount>'.$row_feed['Price'].'</mytags:amount> 
        <mytags:currency>GBP</mytags:currency>
        </mytags:item>';
}
echo '</mytags:items>
</channel>
</rss>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply that cleared the error media type not specific enough, however the Undefined root elements:items is still there. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure, but seeing the RSS you are producing would surely help a lot. Could you add that to the question?

Comment: Edited in the question hope this helps. It seems to be having a problem with <items><item>

Comment: This is validating now, however I do not understand what to put in the xmlns:mytags file. If you point me in the right direction. I presume it is just a file with the tags in it.

Comment: Actually, that attribute can be whatever you want. The main purpose is to make the tag unique, so that your "category" tag doesn't mix up with someone else's. So, you usually put an URI, but it doesn't need to be a real file with something in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can see it is validating properly however feefo still doesn't like the uploaded file. Trying something else now (Dom element). I will accept your answer as correct as I think that it should be, will continue with feefo to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have no xmlns (XML name space) defined. Thus the error is probably due to the fact that the root element *items* is... not defined, as said in the error message. See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) or [that link](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) for explanations on xmlns.

First, to complete the previous answer, after the first echo, add a rss-specific line: `echo '<rss version="2.0">';`

Second, you either need to add an xmlns definition in the above line `echo '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">';` for example, or to change the root element name. try with *channel* or *feed*. Better yet, find a feed which is read by the service you want your feed to be read by, and have a look at the beginning of the file; look for xmlns and root element names.

best,